# Debian install netbeans - "No protocol specified"

Tags: linux, debian, java, terminal

When trying to run the netbeans shell installer, it gives me an error.

```
./netbeans-7.0.1-m1-php-linux.sh
Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Extracting installation data...
Running the installer wizard...
No protocol specified
```

This error came after I did `export DISPLAY=:0.0` because that was an error too. Any ideas?
This is on debian by the way

Comment: I guess you don't run this either in an X session or with `ssh -X`? If it complains about a missing `DISPLAY` variable, it appears to need a GUI, which you are likely lacking or the variable would be present.

Comment: You meant `export DISPLAY=:0.0` not `extract DISPLAY=:0.0`, don't you?

Comment: yes i meant export

Answer (score 1):

I guest this comes too late, but instead of calling it from root you can try as the normal user with:

```
sudo ./netbeans-whatever.sh
```

or

```
sudo sh netbeans-whatever.sh
```

It seems to work also with uninstaller. You can also install as user for the user without using `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to raise the dead, but I came across the same problem recently.

If you have root access, start a x window session as root rather that running the script as root in your current session. When the script is running, it is trying to open the installer in the root's x window session, but one doesn't exists. If you open a session as root and then  run the script from there, it will work.

Comment: Running X as root?!

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://youtu.be/ue7D6K9cFys)  amazing video explains how to solve the error step by step,

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: `sudo sh netbeans-8.2-linux.sh --silent`